# Radio button not changing when clicked inside a jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

So I am required to use a radio button in a jquery tab, next to the tab label.  Everything works fine when a user clicks anywhere on the tab, except when the user clicks directly on the radio button itself.  The tab changes, but the radio button doesn't.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dS8a/).

If you click on text, the tab changes fine, and the radio changes as well, but you click directly on the radio button, the tab changes, but the radio doesn't.

I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is my latest attempt to get it to work

```
$("#tabs > ul > li > a > label > input").on('click',function(){

    var actualRadio = $("[name=biosafetyLevel]:checked").attr('id');

    $('input:radio[name=biosafetyLevel]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
    });

    $("#" + actualRadio).prop('checked', true);
});
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that when you click on input itself checked attribute applies faster than your javascript works. Only way i find out is to give complete function like this:

```
$("#tabs > ul > li > a").on('click',function() {
    var curTab = $(this).attr('id');

    var curRadio = $("input[type='radio']:checked");

    curRadio.prop("checked", false);
    $("#" + curTab + "> label > input").prop('checked', true);
},function(){
$(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

function(){ $(this).prop('checked', true); }); in the end ensures that if someone clicked input itself, it will be cheked in the end, if someone will click "a" DOM element, this thing just wont work cause "a" has no checked property.

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dS8a/30/

Answer (score -1):

1.`$.each()` passes 2 parameters, first is index, second is element.

```
$('input:radio[name=biosafetyLevel]').each(function (i, item) {
        $(item).attr('checked', '')
    });

$("#" + actualRadio).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

2.You do not need to iterate at all

```
$('input:radio[name=biosafetyLevel]').attr('checked', '');
$("#" + actualRadio).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

will do exactly the same.

Comment: I am trying to remove the checks in the .each loop, and then recheck the one that was selected by the user.  Your answer seems to have it backwards.  I did try it in my code, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: ``prop()``method is aviable

Comment: and according to the jQuery docs `prop` is the way to set and unset a checked value.  Also trying your answer with `prop` doesn't work.